# Decimal Rounding

Tags: vb.net, decimal, rounding

I have a project where I need to round a decimal in the following manner:

> If the number is between 12.01 up to 12.49 then it should round to 12.00
>
> If the number is between 12.50 and 12.99,it should round to 13.00

I have tried function Math.Abs and Math.Round but could not achieve the exact results as required above.

Comment: See: [MidpointRounding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding).

Comment: Yes, `Math.Round` is what you want. It will round 12.50 to 13 depending on the arguments. You'll have to show an example of what's failing because this is the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Jacob is correct Math.Round does the job perfectly.
Open a new project (Winforms) and add a Text box, button and label.
Put this code behind the button click event.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Label1.Text = Math.Round(CDec(TextBox1.Text))
End Sub
```

Enter 12.01 to 12.49 in the textbox and it gets rounded down to 12 anything from 12.51 to 13.49 gets rounded to 13

Comment: But 12.5D, where will it decide to go, up or down? (Q: *If the number is between 12.50 and 12.99,it should round to 13.00*).

Answer (score 1):

The following code seems to work for me, it rounds to the nearest whole number. So for example for the number `12.5` it rounds up to 13.
Also, you may change the `0` in the code to change however many decimal places you would like to round to.

```
Dim a As Double = `your number`
Dim rounded As Double = Math.Round(a, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Comment: It _seems_ to have solved the issue but will need more testing.Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: If you think this solved your problem, could you please mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As banf pointed out add the additional parameters to the Math.Round function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = Math.Round(CDec(TextBox1.Text), 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
End Sub